# Print Multiple Objects

Tags: java, swing, paint

Hi I am trying to get my program to move the shapes I create across the screen and for some reason its not working Im not sure whats happening? It has to be something small can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
 public class MultipleObs extends JFrame {
  private JPanel paintPanel;
  public MultipleObs() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
    getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private java.util.List<Shape> shapes;
    private Shape mouseOverShape=null;
    int x=0, velX=2;
    javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(5,this);
    public PaintPanel(){
        super();
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Float(x,25,25,25));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, 15, 60, 30));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, 35, 60, 30));
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (Shape s : shapes){
            g2.draw(s);
        }
        tm.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        x = x+ velX;
        repaint();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MultipleObs().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. Do not ever start a Swing Timer inside of paintComponent. That method should be  for painting and painting only. Instead start the Timer in the constructor.
2. When you create an Ellipse2D object, its position is fixed. Changing one of the variables used to create it will have no effect on the already created object.

A possible solution is to not use Ellipse2D's but instead draw ovals using `Graphics#drawOval(...)` inside of paintComponent and use the changing x field in that method call. If you must use Ellipse2D's, then you will need to translate them some way, perhaps by using an AffineTransform, but this way is a bit more complicated since I think that you'd have to wrap your Ellipse2D into a Path2D for this to work.

Another option: create a BufferedImage sprite, draw your complex shapes into the BufferedImage using a Graphics2D object obtained from the BufferedImage, and then draw that within paintComponent via `drawImage(myImage, imageX, imageY, null)`, and change the imageX in your Timer.

Comment: Where should I start the timer. Thanks for you help :) @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: See what I used before was Graphics g

                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(i, 100, 20, 10);

But I cant put that into an arraylist @Hovercraft